# Javascript not registering the value from onClick button and appending it to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am working on a project where people can reply to each other. It works on a simple basis. You click the reply button next to the persons name and it appends their username (from the value of the button) to the text area in [] brackets.

I am getting a problem with the javascript that it always adds in the same username instead of the rest.

I have a JSFiddle here that showcases my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/zevpbghe/

```
<script text="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.reply').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#field');
        var username = $('.reply');
        text.val(text.val() + username.val());    
    });
});
</script>
```

I need to get the value from a class because I have multiple users.

```
<ul>
<li>Adam Sandler<button style='border: none; background-color: transparent !important; cursor:pointer; font-size:12px;color:#3F729B' class='reply' value='[AdamSandler]'>Reply</button></li>
<li>Mike Tomson<button style='border: none; background-color: transparent !important; cursor:pointer; font-size:12px;color:#3F729B' class='reply' value='[MikeTomson]'>Reply</button></li>  
<li>James Bradly<button style='border: none; background-color: transparent !important; cursor:pointer; font-size:12px;color:#3F729B' class='reply' value='[JamesBradly]'>Reply</button></li>
```

Once the class 'reply' is clicked it shoud append the data from the value to the text area:

```
<textarea id="field"></textarea>
```

Comment: $('.reply') would return an array of objects. Loop through the objects and get the val

Comment: @bigbounty Thanks for the reply first off! Secondly would you be so kind to supply a fiddle I am not a wiz at jquery and jscript. It would help me alot!

Comment: People have answered now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('.reply').on('click', function () {
        var text = $('#field');
        text.val(text.val() + $(this).val());    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `$('.reply')` to `$(this)`.

```
var username = $(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for this guys. You are life savers!

Comment: Glad to be of help, and please accept answer so that others can get help from it as well, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your function, `$('.reply')` gets all of the reply in the page and then using `.val()` on that collection will take the value of the first one, which is Adam Sandler.

You probably want to get the reply you've clicked on: with jQuery, it's pretty easy, you just have to do `var username = $(this);`

Comment: Thank you for this guys. You are life savers!